# Traefik, docker, fastapi with TCP and HTTP entrypoints?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, fastapi, traefik

I'm new to Traefik and Docker (and yaml). I would like to have FastAPI communicate with a PostgreSQL database in a Docker container with Traefik as reverse proxy.

I have two python files, one with the FastAPI code, `main.py` and the other a database handler, `db_config.py`.

I can set it up so that I can run `db_config.py` directly and successfully connect to the database with TCP, but I can't get it to accept HTTP as well from `main.py`. I suspect my yml files are misconfigured.

I tried to piece together the yaml as best I could follow with Sebastian Ramirez's demonstration--though he wasn't using something like postgres, and so didn't need the tcp parts.

Here are my files:

db_config.py:

```
import os

import psycopg


def get_params():
    db = {
        "dbname": "postgres",
        "user": "postgres",
        "password": os.environ['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'],
        "host": os.environ['IP'],
        "port": "5432"
    }
    return db

def main():
    params = get_params()
    sql = """SELECT to_regclass('public.testtable');"""
    with psycopg.connect(**params) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(sql,)
            res = cur.fetchone()

    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

docker-compose.traefik.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  backend:

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    restart: always
    container_name: traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true 
      - --api.dashboard=true 
      - --api.debug=true 
      - --log.level=DEBUG 
      - --providers.docker=true 
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false 
      - --providers.docker.network=backend 
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80 
      - --accesslog
      - --log
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`monitor.localhost`)" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
networks:
  backend:

services:
  pg:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
      networks:
        - backend
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=backend"
        - "traefik.tcp.routers.mytcprouter.entrypoints=backend"
        - "traefik.tcp.routers.postgres.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
        - "traefik.tcp.services.postgres.loadbalancer.server.port=5432"
  app:
    image: traefik_test
    depends_on:
      - pg
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
      - IP=pg
    networks:
      - backend
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=backend"
      - "traefik.http.services.custodiancont.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.routers.web.entrypoints=backend"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8

COPY ./app /app/
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. I removed pg from traefik's management (so no `- "traefik.enable=true"` label). Everything is working as expected (though I may still have some unnecessary aspects to my yml files).